# Given A List of Branches, How to Find a List of Tree List That Are Singly Connected Together

Tags: c#, graph

Let's say I have a list of branches, how to find a list of tree list that are singly connected together? The below diagram should illustrate my point. The input is a list of branches in a single tree, as labeled, ie. `1`, `2`, `3` and so on

[image]

Comment: The input, or the output?  The question sounds like you want the list on the left...but if it's the input, then it'd be something you already have.

Comment: @CHao, The input is a list of trees, `1`, `2`, `3` and so on

Comment: ...k, the input doesn't make much sense to me.  Should i assume that all the "trees" are actually connected (and thus part of the same tree)?   And if so, why are you passing them as a list of nodes, rather than as a single tree?

Comment: @cHao, all the trees are connected, but I want to group them into singly connected tree list

Comment: @cHao - Yea, that's what I saw. Saw it not as a list of tree's, but a single large tree.

Comment: @Kyle, I've updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: @cHao, I've updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: @Ngu - Is it not the case that each branch, or node, has a maximum of only two nodes per branch?

Comment: @Kyle, not, each branch can have more than two nodes per branch, as illustrated in the diagram above

Comment: @Ngu - I just saw now what you mean. Have you tried what I suggested, just enumerating through the children?

Comment: @Kyle, that would be a good idea, actually that line was what I thought as well, just asked here to learn if there is any better methods of attacking

Comment: I don't think so, but I could be wrong. It's still pretty much following normal tree logic and should be performant enough for your needs.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up with you, I see you accepted the answer. Did it all work out?

Comment: @Kyle, yes it did. I used a modified version of your algorithm and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is as follows:

1. Create a function that accepts a tree node as a parameter
2. If the node has no children, print the value of the current node and return.
3. If the node has two children, end the current list of single node values, then recurse into the left node, then the right node
4. If the node has one child, add it to the list of values contained in the tree, then recurse into that node.
5. Continue.

Comment: @What if a node has more than two children?

Comment: @Ngu - It shouldn't though? Sorry, I'm assuming by your image that this is a binary tree?

Comment: it's not binary; as can be seen from tree `5`,`6`,`7`,`8`

Comment: Define "right node", for a tree with 3 children.  Seems we're not dealing with binary trees here.

Comment: @Ngu , @cHao - What one could do is follow the same process, however you'll have to enumerate the children if the amount of children is: `> 1`.

Answer (score 1):

According to image, there is a really simple solution.
Let's make a list, with elements, that are lists of the same type. Procedure will be called tree_lists(list, tree). All you need to do is:

1. Looking at current joint, you
   have your list pointer on the first
   element of list.
2. If there are
       **more than one** child in current node: iterate through each
   subtree, incrementing list pointer
   and calling
   tree_lists(list[i],current_subtree)
   where i is list pointer and
   current_subtree is current subtree
   =)
3. If ony one child exists, just add this joint to the current list item and move on to next.
4. Of course, list pointer and list values must be somehow global and modified in recurion as well.